# Research fund for PhD students in Italy

Tags: phd, funding, italy

Are there any sources where I can find the information regarding the research funds for PhD students and the purposes list on which it can be used?
There is 10% of annual stipend amount available as research fund for PhD students in my University, however I cannot find the regulations for it in English, only in Italian.
I know that these money might be used to cover the travelling expenses for the conferences, but what I wonder is if I can transfer these money to my stipend if I don't use it totally?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something, but it sounds like you should be asking your university this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but what I wonder is if I can transfer these money to my stipend if I don't use it totally?

No, usually you can't.

In Italy, typically, funds cannot be transferred directly to non-employees (a PhD student is not an employee of a university), and only certain funds, like those coming from research contracts, can be transferred to employees. In the latter case, the payment should be approved by the department.

Moreover, as a PhD student, you are probably not even directly responsible of those research funds, which are probably under the responsibility of your advisor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the regulations of your institution, but normally, in Italy like anywhere in the world, one is not allowed to transfer research funds directly into their pockets, for many good reasons. There are strict regulations on which expenses and activities you can use them for, to prevent abuses.